# Download and run dmg file from unidentified uploader

Tags: macos, safari, dmg

I have made a dmg file for my uploader desktop application. This dmg is ported on my website from where i download the same using the Safari Browser. However, when i try to execute it from the downloads folder, the system does not execute it and throws a message stating its from an unidentified developer. Hence, in Security & Privacy settings, i opted to allow download. I cannot expect all the users to do this setting. What modifications do i need to do inorder to make the dmg to run without any such errors/warnings. I am a novice at this, kindly requesting for some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Become a verified developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an unverified app on mac by right-clicking the DMG and selecting open, this will pop up a warning but as opposed to doubled clicking, there is an option to continue.

See this article for screenshots - http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/

The only other option is to pay Apple to become a verified developer, and then have your app reviewed and added to the Mac app store.